# Decode HTML response in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a string which i get from the response and it is like this

```
@"status=y&message=Not+available&code=110";
```

Now i want to parse the string and get all the key-value pairs.
OR
Can i get a dictionary with all the key-value pairs from the string above 
Thank u in advance
@raaaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString* queryPart in [yourResponseAsNSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
  NSArray* keyValue = [queryPart componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
  [parameters setObject:[keyValue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[keyValue objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```